# JUnit - Run specific tests using JUnitCore

Tags: java, selenium, junit, automation

I have a couple of classes which contain Tests.
I have a main method that uses JUnitCore in order to run all tests.

What can I do in order to run specific tests in each class?

Currently I use something like this to run all my tests :

```
      Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(TestJunit.class, TestJunit2.class);
```

Maybe there is a possibility to categorize the relevant tests and then run them using JUnitCore ?? Thanks !

Comment: why would you have a main method? have your tests as a part of your build process

Comment: It has to be in a different project by company demands. Any help with the issue ?

Comment: unit tests in a different project .... talking about insane. but, if so: why not integrate it as a part of the build process of the 'different project'? unit tests are not supposed to run using a main method

Answer (score 2):

You can build a `org.junit.runner.Request` by providing class and method name and pass it to `run` method of `JUnitCore`class. This will execute given test of the specified class.

```
Request request = Request.method(TestClass.class, "methodName");
Result result = new JUnitCore().run(request);
```

You can check the result of test by invoking `wasSuccessful()` method available in Result class .

Comment: I tried that already, but I would like to run more than 1 method per class. Any solution for that ?

Comment: @NativBarak can't you refactor your tests and split them in different classes?